# Override application.hbs template in Emberjs

Tags: templates, ember.js, routes, overriding

In emberjs, I am in a situation that my application already has routes template that uses the application.hbs template, but now I want to create a new route templates that doesn't use application.hbs.

Is there any easy solution for that?

I have seen many answers but that doesn't match my specification and also my version of ember is 2.11.

Thank you.

Comment: application.hbs is the root template. if you don't want to use it, you'll need to restructure your routes.

it may be possible to extract what is currently in application.hbs into application/index.hbs

Comment: If this is due to wanting different layouts, https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/05/03/reusable-page-layouts-ember/ I would move the variable display to the children routes

Answer (score 1):

Keep application.hbs as minimal and common across all routes as you can. What you shoud do is generate top level routes for your application.

Say you have a common setup where you have an authenticated section, post login, and a login section. It is common for pre and post login to have differing top level templates. Try something like this:

ember g route login
ember g route login/index
ember g route login/forgot-password
ember g route authenticated
ember g route authenticated/index
ember g route authenticated/profile
etc...

Your login.hbs would have its own style, and potentially child routes, which will assume that style and place subsequent nested templates in the {{outlet}} that others have mentioned.

File Structure:

```
routes/
-login/
----index.hbs
----forgot-password.hbs
-authenticated/
----index.hbs
----profile.hbs
login.hbs
authenticated.hbs
application.hbs
```

In the example above, login.hbs might look like this:

```
{{yellow-navbar}}
{{outlet}}
```

and authenticated.hbs like this:

```
{{pink-navbar}}
{{user.name}}
{{outlet}}
```

Now, the login/index.hbs and login/forgot-password.hbs templates will render in the login.hbs outlet. both of these pages will render a yellow navbar, and then their own content.

Because authenticated.hbs is another top level parent route, both authenticated/index.hbs and authenticated/profile.hbs will render their content beneath a pink navbar and a display of the current user's name.

if your application.hbs looked like this:

```
{{#general-site-container}}
  <h2>Website Name</h2>
  {{outlet}}
{{/general-site-container}}
```

Then all of the routes, both authenticated and login, will be in the general-site-container, and will all show the h2 with the website name.

An important note in this, and something that I see a lot of people get confused with, is that this folder structure does not dictate the actual path of the route.

The router might be configured like this, to avoid showing "authenticated" in the url:
Router.js

```js
  // login.index route assumed at root url /login
  this.route('login', { path: '/login' }, function() {
    // avail at /login/forgot-password
    this.route('forgot-password', { path: '/forgot-password' }
  });

  //authenticated.index.hbs assumed at root avail at /
  //notice that the authenticated parent route has a route of "/"
  this.route('authenticated', { path: '/' }, function() { 

    // authenticated.profile route avail at /profile
    this.route('profile', { path: '/profile' });

    // as an exmaple you can further nest content to your desire
    // if for instance your profile personal info section has a parent 
    // template/route
    this.route('', { path: '/personal-info' }, function() {
      this.route('address', { path: '/address' }); //profile/personal-info/address
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to use `{{outlet}}` for achieve this. 
create diffrent outlets where you need to show diffrent templates by overriding application template

```
{{outlet}} //application hbs default one

{{outlet "view1"}} // another template

{{outlet "view2"}} //another template
```

there should be `view1.hbs` and `view2.hbs` in order to render those templates

Comment: Infact, whenever I create two views, like in this case view1.hbs and view2.hbs then these views will already use the application.hbs template. My problem is that how can I override the application.hbs if I create a new route templates.

Comment: what you can do is render {{outlet}} in the application.hbs. keep application.hbs just to renderOutlets nothing else move the things you have in the application.hbs in to a child template which can render through application.hbs so the logics which to render and how to render should be in the application controller. according to that it will renderOutlet.

Comment: assume you need to render pages according to the user levels for different templates, you can have the logic in the application controller to check the currentUser access level and render the template accordingly - keep the application.hbs clean